# How to detect a collision between two objects in an Array (Sprite Kit)

Tags: arrays, collections, sprite-kit

I have an array of Bullets and Enemies objects. I want the game to check each element in the arrays to see whether there was a collision between the two or not. If there was any collision, then damage that enemy and delete the bullet. Right now every time a bullet hits an enemy it decreases the health of ALL the enemies in the array, thus killing them all at once. How can I make it so that it only decreases the health of the enemy which I'm shooting at?

```
 //This function handles our collision detection
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        //print("COLLISIONS!")
        // If contact is with another object
        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == pickupCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == playerCategory
        {
            displayText(text: "Picked up Pistol")
            player.setHasPistol(gotPistol: true)
            pistol.removeFromParent()
        }

        //Bullet hits an object
        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == objectCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory
        {
            bulletCleanup(killNow: true)
            //print("BULLET HAS HIT THE PIPE!")
        }

        //Do collisions between bullets and enemies...
        for bullet in bulletList
        {
            for enemy in enemyList
            {
                //if the enemy was hit have them take damage.
                if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory
                {
                    //deletes the bullet after hitting an object
                    bulletCleanup(killNow: true)

                    //apply damage
                    enemy.setHitPoints(setPoints: enemy.getHitPoints() - pistol.getDamage())

                    // print("BULLET HAS HIT THE enemy!!!!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`didBegin(contact:)` is called for a single collision between one specific object and another specific object. (actually between physics bodies...)

Your problem is occurring because you are iterating over **every** bullet and **every** enemy for a single collision and at each iteration you are testing if the collision was between a bullet and an enemy, which it was, so you are applying the damage to every enemy.

All you need to do is to extract the specific enemy from the `SKPhysicsContact` object and apply damage to that particular enemy.

Also, I suspect you are missing some contacts because for your contact tests, you are not checking if the `bodyA` and `bodyB` physics bodies are reversed i.e.

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == pickupCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == playerCategory
```

`bodyA` might be `player` and `bodyB` might be `pickup`, so you need to test for this also.

Here is an alternative `didBegincontact()` you might find helpful (It's Swift2, but that shouldn't be a big problem):

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

switch contactMask {

   case pickupCategory  | playerCategory
        displayText(text: "Picked up Pistol")
        player.setHasPistol(gotPistol: true)

       let pistol = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == pickupCategory) ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!

        pistol.removeFromParent()

   case objectCategory | bulletCategory
        bulletCleanup(killNow: true)
        //print("BULLET HAS HIT THE PIPE!")

   case enemyCategory| bulletCategory

        //deletes the bullet after hitting an object
        bulletCleanup(killNow: true)

        //apply damage
       let enemy = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory) ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!
        enemy.setHitPoints(setPoints: enemy.getHitPoints() - pistol.getDamage())

   default :
       //Some other contact has occurred
       print("Some other contact")
   }
}
```

I'm not sure how your `bulletCleanup()` function works - you don't appear to be sending it a specific bullet object so I don't know how it knows which bullet to process. The specific bullet involved in the contact can be obtained in `didBegincContact:` as follows:

```
       let bullet = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == bulletCategory) ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!
```

which is a short form of saying "is `nodeA`'s `categoryBitMask` a `bulletCategory`? If it is, then set `bullet` equal to `nodeA`, otherwise set `bullet` to `nodeB`.

Note that if your categories are more complicated (i.e. objects can belong to multiple categories), this won't work as the simple AND tests (`enemyCategory| bulletCategory`) won't match.

Comment: You might also want to ask yourself why you are keeping arrays of bullets and enemies. You might have a very real reason but there are are other ways to access these nodes - the children[] property of the SKScene and the enumerateChildNodesWithName() functions to name but 2.

Comment: Hey man thank for your response! I really appreciate it! Now I know why my collisions were only happening half the time! However, I still don't understand this part, "All you need to do is to extract the specific enemy from the SKPhysicsContact object and apply damage to that particular enemy." How do I do that without iterating though my array? In your example you have "enemy.setHitPoints(setPoints: enemy.getHitPoints() - pistol.getDamage())". So how do I tell the function what "enemy" is or which one I'm talking about.

Comment: @SamTrent  The SKOhysics contact has 2 properties - bodyA and bodyB. These ar SKOhysicsBodies and each of these has a property 'node', which is the node associated with that physics body. So the line fo code 'let enemy = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory? contact.bodyA....' creates a temporary SKNode equal to the actual enemy involved in the collision.

Comment: Ah I see. I I'm trying it out in my code and it says that "Value of type 'SKNode' has no member setHitPoints", referring to "enemy.setHitPoints...." Is this because my enemy class inherits from SKSpriteNode? Is there a way to use 'contact.bodyA.spriteNode' instead of 'contact.bodyA.node'?

Comment: Hey I got it! This is what I did, ' let enemy: Enemy = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory ? contact.bodyA.node! as! Enemy: contact.bodyB.node! as! SKSpriteNode as! Enemy)
         enemy.setHitPoints(setPoints: enemy.getHitPoints() - pistol.getDamage())" I just casted everything over to Enemy. Not sure if this is the best thing to do but it worked! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @SamTrent - you got it. A lot (all?) of the functions whereby Sprite-kit returns a node to your code, it'll be returned as an SKNode, so you'll have to cast it to what you're expecting or test it e.g. when using enumerateChildNodesWithName it's common to do a 'if let myNode =  returnedNode as! xxxx etc.